# Understanding an application launch from web

Tags: browser, reverse-engineering

I'm curious as to how an application is being launched from a web control panel. I am using Splashtop Business, a remote desktop management system. The system allows one to select a workstation to connect to, select "Connect", and the native app will be launched, and initiate the connection.

I want to know how this app is being launched, with the information being transmitted from the browser to the application.

- I checked the official documentation, and couldn't find anything on a custom URI being used for the application I'm using.
- I watched the network traffic, and found the only thing of plausible importance (in my eyes) was a cookie being set. (I can clean and post some cookies if that would be helpful.)
- I watched the local storage of the browser, nothing changed between different launches.

---

Other things of import:

- The site said pop-ups needed to be enabled for the application to launch
- There is a small delay while the site says it is "Locating the Splashtop Business app"
- This works in multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome)

Any plausible solutions and especially ways to verify this would be appreciated. I don't want to accept that "its a blackbox solution" and just try and find another way to do the same thing. I'd rather know what is going on with my computer, as this is fairly significant in respect to security.

Comment: You might have to use a debugger to step through the JavaScript code execution line-by-line to see which line triggers the application to launch. That's the nuclear option, IMO, if you can't find any other way.